How to smooth the mesh to make it smooth
Mirror and screw modifiers are used.
Could you please advise on the following questions:

How to smooth the edges on the surface to get a smooth transition?
How to smooth the surface to make it smoother without a hump?

Download .blend

Hello maybe first thing dissolve some edge loops in order to have a more regular gap between them?

It looks as if you may have a Mirror modifier on that object. If you do, make sure you don't have an internal face between the halves.

Yes, there is a mirror modifier.
But when using it and removing extra edge, the hump does not disappear

again please share your file, it will help

Please, help!:(
